# Can't export a table, it only export the letter

Tags: export, table

I have been trying to export a table for the first time and I don't understand why it doesn't work. This is what I have written:

```
For[i = 0, i <= 9, i++,
 R[i] = Table[
   SolveValues[7024.39051*Log[10, 0.0012*x + 1] - 1.51752*x == i, x]]
 ]

Export["C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\text.text", R, "Table"]
FilePrint["C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\text.text"]
```

The output that I get is only the letter R. I tried to export a single set of values with

```
Export["C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\text.text", R[1], "Table"]
FilePrint["C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\text.text"]
```

And here it works perfectly.

Does anybody knows what I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is a bit weird: for one, you have a table without an iterator. Since you already know `Table`, use that to iterate the values of `i` instead of `For`. The significant advantage is that `Table` returns its output, so you can easily save it in a variable for further use, whereas `For` and other looping constructs return `Null`.

For isntance:

```
ClearAll[i, R]

R = 
 Table[
   SolveValues[7024.39051*Log[10, 0.0012*x + 1] - 1.51752*x == i, x], 
   {i, 0, 9}
 ]
```

And then you can export `R` directly.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I got the habit of using For for this kind of things when I was writing in C++, I need to get rid of this habit here.